# What is RSS Error?

Tags: sensor, error, documentation

I was reading through documentation for an INA219 sensor from TI (http://www.ti.com/product/INA219), and they have a chart for RSS Error.

What does RSS stand for?

[image]

Comment: Residual Sum of Squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it probably means [Root of Sum of Squares](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68395.html).

The chart on the linked page is actually a dynamic chart generated using Javascript, so we can look at the code. The last line combines a couple of error sources as:

```
var total_error_room_temperature = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(total_vos_error_temperature,2)+
    Math.pow(gain_error_temperature,2));
```

So the function used in the chart to combine errors is:

$$e_{total} = \sqrt{e_1^2 + e_2^2}$$

This is a the square root of the sum of the squares.

---

The other meaning for RSS that appears to be more common in general is [Residual Sum of Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares), used in linear regression calculations, but does not apply here.